# Is Delegators really Categories in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, categories

I'm trying to understand the Informal protocols, until now I know that Informal protocols are a kind of Category, but, why delegators don't have a category name?

Example:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class FileSystemNode;

@interface AppController : NSObject { // Where is the Category ????  
@private
    IBOutlet NSBrowser *_browser;
    FileSystemNode *_rootNode;
}

@end
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Categories vs Informal Protocols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183396/categories-vs-informal-protocols)

Answer (score 1):

Informal protocols are **not** "a kind of category".

If a class conforms to a protocol (for example `@interface MyClass <MyProtocol>`) it is guaranteed that you can call all methods on that class that are required by `MyProtocol`. (Unless the class doesn't really implement them [the linker can't know that because of dynamic binding], which is a programming error and a lie, but that is usually not the case.)

Categories on the other hand allow you to take an already existing class and extend it with new methods (for example adding a `removeAllSubviews` method to the already existing `NSView` class).

---

So, categories and protocols are quite the opposite of each other.

Comment: So, in that example, what "AppController" really is?

Comment: @LuizSiqueiraNeto in your example, `AppController` is a subclass of `NSObject`. It is neither a category nor a protocol. If your intent was to make it the application delegate, you should make it conform to `NSApplicationDelegate` (i.e. `@interface AppController : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>`).

Comment: Thanks, I believe that you are right, but when I delegate to AppController what really is happen? I mean, is a kind of injection, a callback or just it try to call some method in AppController without know if it is there? I know Java and Delphi, for me looks like a bad idea to delegate to a class that don't have a formal relationship, like a "Protocol" to prevent a execution time error.

Comment: The equivalent of `@interface MyClass <MyProtocol>` in Java would be something like `class MyClass implements MyProtocol`.