# What's the difference between formal and informal protocols in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos

What's the difference between formal and informal protocols in Objective-C?

Comment: About informal protocol described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010058/informal-protocol-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html)

> Formal and Informal Protocols
>
> There are two varieties of protocol,
>   formal and informal:
>
> - An **informal** protocol is a category on NSObject, which implicitly
>     makes almost all objects adopters of
>     the protocol. (A category is a
>     language feature that enables you to
>     add methods to a class without
>     subclassing it.) Implementation of the
>     methods in an informal protocol is
>     optional. Before invoking a method,
>     the calling object checks to see
>     whether the target object implements
>     it. Until optional protocol methods
>     were introduced in Objective-C 2.0,
>     informal protocols were essential to
>     the way Foundation and AppKit classes
>     implemented delegation.
> - A **formal** protocol declares a list of methods that client classes
>     are expected to implement. Formal
>     protocols have their own declaration,
>     adoption, and type-checking syntax.
>     You can designate methods whose
>     implementation is required or optional
>     with the @required and @optional
>     keywords. Subclasses inherit formal
>     protocols adopted by their ancestors.
>     A formal protocol can also adopt other
>     protocols.
>
> Formal protocols are an extension to
>   the Objective-C language.

Comment: so "informal protocol" is just another name for category?

Comment: Then what does `@required` and `@optional` do ?

Comment: "informal protocol" is category and "formal protocol" is delegate?

Comment: Can I have a example of "informal protocol"?

Comment: @allenlinli NSKeyValueCoding is an informal protocol

Comment: @byJeevan `@required` and `@optional` are keywords on formal protocols to indicate that methods are required or not required, respectively, to be implemented by the object that is adhereing to it.

Comment: The important thing to note about informal protocols is that they were used heavily before the `@optional` keyword was introduced to formal protocols in Objective-C 2.0. Before the optional keyword, it was the only way to have an optional protocol method.

Comment: @lostAtSeaJoshua Do we have this concept of Informal protocols in Swift ?

Answer (score 16):

**Informal Protocol** : `Category` (Implementations are Optional)

**Formal Protocol** : `Extension` (Implementations are Optional and required)

Comment: Are Category methods implementations are optional? I don't think so, because I commented a method implementation and immediately I can see error "Method definition for 'xxxmethod' is missing". The xxxmethod is declared in .h file.

Comment: Simplest way of describing difference.

Answer (score 2):

The Objective-C language provides a way to formally declare a list of methods (including declared properties)
as a protocol. Formal protocols are supported by the language and the runtime system. For example, the
compiler can check for types based on protocols, and objects can introspect at runtime to report whether
or not they conform to a protocol.