# Delegate variables in an informal protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Say I create an object in class Foo called Bar.  Bar's delegate is Foo and I want to access a variable from Foo like this `[self.delegate variable]`.  Not surprisingly, this will work but give a warning saying "No -variable method found"  So my question is, how do I declare that I want this variable to be accessed by a delegate without rewriting the getters and setters?

For example, if I wanted to declare delegate methods, it would look something like this:

```
@interface NSObject(Foo)
- (void)someMethod;
@end
```

How do I do the same with variables?

Answer (score 3):

The standard pattern is to define a `protocol` that the delegate conforms to.  For example:

```
@protocol BarDelegate
- (void) someMethod;
- (id) variable;
@end
```

Then in `Bar.h` you declare your delegate like:

```
@interface Bar : NSObject {
    id<BarDelegate> delegate;
}

//alternately:
@property(nonatomic, retain) id<BarDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

And in `Foo.h` you declare that you conform to the protocol:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject<BarDelegate> {
}
@end
```

Then the compiler warnings will go away.

Comment: Can you do the same with an informal protocol though?

Comment: As long as the members you want access to are exposed via getter functions, you should be able to do `@interface NSObject(Foo) - (id)variable;  @end`, though according to [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010058/informal-protocol-in-objective-c) creating informal protocols by adding categories on NSObject has fallen out of favor.

Comment: The `@optional` keyword is only available in newer versions of OS X. If you want to support older versions, an informal protocol is still required.