# Protocols & delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Notifications, Delegates, and Protocols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118598/what-is-the-difference-between-notifications-delegates-and-protocols)

I am new in **Objective C**. Would like to understand the concept of `Protocols` and `Delegates` in a few words. Like under what situation should I consider declaring a `Protocol`, and then consume it in my classes as delegates or let other classes consume it.

Instead of `Protocols` why can't I make my classes do the same job?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Notifications, Delegates, and Protocols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118598/) also [Difference between delegates and protocols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431413/difference-between-protocol-and-delegates) also [Delegate vs. protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361958/delegate-vs-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

Protocols are like contracts, Your class must implement all methods that are @required, @optional are on the other hand not required.

> Instead of Protocols why can't I make my classes do the same job?
>   You can, but like I wrote above, its a contract. You know that 
>   class

implements the  (Required) methods.

delegate is (should be) a weak reference to the class that implements the given protocol.

You are recommended to use the following attribute on your delegateproperty:

```
@property (assign) id<yourProtocol> delegate;
```

Notice that you don't retain your delegate. You you (weak) reference because you dont want to get into a retain circle (A retains B, and B retains A).

I hope my explanation helped a bit.