# Cannot get iOS http post to work using NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, post, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to get a POST message working. I've seen a couple of posts describing doing so, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148900/append-data-to-a-post-nsurlrequest), but I still cannot get it working. Below is my objective-c code:

```
NSString * urlString = @"http://magicthegatheringdatabase.com/test.php";
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tes1=%@&test2=%@",
                        [@"hello" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                        [@"world" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData * postBody = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody: postBody];

[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postBody.length];
[request addValue: postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSError * error = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                           returningResponse: nil
                                                       error: &error];
NSLog(@"%p, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);

NSString * returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", returnString);
```

And here is my PHP:

```
<?php
  print_r($_REQUEST);
  print_r($_POST);
  print_r($_GET);

  echo file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
?>
```

If I run the code, I get the following logged:

```
2012-12-19 09:24:09.061 MTG Deck Builder[7921:570f] 0x0, (null)
2012-12-19 09:24:09.062 MTG Deck Builder[7921:570f] Result: Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

If I navigate directly to the url and append `?test1=hello&test2=world` (using GET obviously instead of POST) I get:

```
Array
(
    [test1] => hello
    [test2] => world
    [phpbb3_5e63r_u] => 1
    [phpbb3_5e63r_k] => 
    [phpbb3_5e63r_sid] => 7ff37e188aa8e0ab57fae6a52f0d1f7b
    [__utma] => 86369156.392372889.1349352986.1352901458.1353328580.11
    [__utmz] => 86369156.1351935106.8.2.utmcsr=hankinsoft.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/website/forum/10-mtg-magic-the-gathering-trading-card-game-tcg-da/634-new-forum.html
    [style_cookie] => null
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [test1] => hello
    [test2] => world
)
```

So I know my PHP is logging the get/requests properly, but I'm not sure why my POST via the objective-c code is not working. I'm pretty sure that I'm overlooking something stupid. Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Comment: Try by setting the content type and size.

Comment: Do one more thing instead of setting nil to error, pass some instance of NSError, so you can know what the error is coming. Hope, it'll sort your prob.

Comment: Btw, you want to hear about [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit).

Comment: @moonwave99 btw you want to avoid RestKit when possible by any means. That framework is a monster.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've tried adding the content-type and content-size (updated my questions with the details), but still no luck. Additionally I include error details. No error was detected.

Comment: pls can anyone help me? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861504/nsurlconnection-with-post-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `NSURLConnection` doesn't handle redirections properly.

When you send the `POST` request to the URL `http://magicthegatheringdatabase.com/test.php`, the server respond with `301 Moved Permanently` and redirects to `http://www.magicthegatheringdatabase.com/test.php`.

Instead of sending the same request to the new URL, `NSURLConnection` creates a new `GET` request and discards the original request's `HTTPBody`. THis behavior is due to the [HTTP specifications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) that forbid the automatic redirection of requests other than `HEAD` and `GET` without a confirmation from the user. Changing the method to `GET` is erroneous but at least it is a safe method, which cannot harm the HTTP resource.

This problem can be solved with two options:

1. You may simply change the URL of the request to be `http://www.magicthegatheringdatabase.com/test.php`.
2. Or you may create an instance of `NSURLConnection` with a delegate and implement the `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` in order to handle the redirection properly as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783499/nsurlrequest-how-to-handle-a-redirected-post). This will work even if the redirection changes but requires you to write more code as you need to wait for the response, create a `NSMutableData` object, append the bytes as they come and handle everything asynchronously (see [Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)). However, performing tasks asynchronously is always a good idea: you can cancel them if needed and you don't risk blocking your thread for a long a time (when you're in the main thread, anything longer than 1 second is a long time).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the details. I knew I had to be overlooking something simple and this did it.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to add the following:

`[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tes1=%@&test2=%@", 
                           [@"hello" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                           [@"world" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Now add

```
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```