# NSURLConnection with POST doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm trying request a URL parsing parameters with POST, **but mypage.php is not receiving this parameters...**
Here is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/mypage.php"]];
NSString *params = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"name=%@&surname=%@&location=%@&email=%@&password=%@&gender=%@&tipo=%@", name, surname, location, email, password, gender, tipo];                   
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(params);
NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
}
```

and mypage.php

```
if($_POST['name'] != "" && $_POST['email'] != "") 
//Here the $_POST['name'] and the $_POST['email'] are empty...
```

Comment: Please read the description for the "Xcode" tag. It is not appropriate to your question.

Comment: Just a hint:  Any time you title a question with "<some language feature> doesn't work" you instantly prejudice many readers against you.  In all probability <some language feature> works just fine, but you simply don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not starting the connection. You should do it with a `[conn start];`

Comment: 'it doesn't work' is unhelpful. Are there any console log messages? Errors? Are you implementing any delegate methods? How do you know that it's empty in your script and the script isn't just not called? Can you post the *complete* code?

Comment: I have already explained what I mean with "doesn't work" the result is "<br>" not enter in condition from mypage.php if($_POST['name'] != "" && $_POST['email'] != "")

Comment: Bruno the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJDDIDG) states: “Returns an initialized URL connection and begins to load the data for the URL request.”

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *params=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&surname=%@&location=%@&email=%@&password=%@&gender=%@&tipo=%@", name, surname, location, email, password, gender, tipo];
NSData *postData=[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/mypage.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (data!=nil) {
   NSString *output=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSLog(@"output: %@", output);
}else{
   NSLog(@"data is empty");
}
```