# How to add <NSXMLParserDelegate> in interface declaration without getting errors in older version like iOS 3.2

Tags: iphone, ios

The below works for iOS4.0 and above but when on building with base iOS3.2 i get an error "cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSXMLParserDelegate'"
Thanks

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_4_0
@interface MyClass: NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>

    #else

@interface MyClass: NSObject

    #endif

{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol is an [informal protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010058/informal-protocol-in-objective-c) prior to iOS4 which basically means that all the methods are `@optional`

The declaration of adopted protocols just keeps the compiler happy so dont do it in this case.

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
```

And rather than attempting to setup the class as conforming to the protocol at compile time do it at runtime.

```
-(BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol
{
    NSString *protocolName = NSStringFromProtocol(aProtocol);

    if ([protocolName isEqualToString:@"NSXMLParserDelegate"]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return [super conformsToProtocol:aProtocol];

}

-(void)setupParser
{


    myParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:whatever];

    //cast as id to shut the compiler warning up    
    myParser.delegate = (id)self;


}
```

Possibly the override on `-(BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol` isnt needed but it probably wont hurt.

Answer (score 2):

I think your bigger problem is that you're still trying to support iOS 3.2. Almost everyone has dropped support for it (including Apple, since the lowest iOS target supported by the iOS 6 SDK is 4.3)

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Agree. Regardless of whether the activity makes sense the question is reasonable and deserves an answer