# With Swift "why" do some delegate functions require override func

Tags: macos, swift, delegates

OK, so I understand delegates.  I am perplexed (in a language design sense) that in some recent Swift work I have encountered delegates that can only be implemented with an "override" qualifier.  Specifically "controlTextDidEndEditing" as NSTextFieldDelegate of a NSTextField UI element.  (Yes, this is OS X dev work, not IOS).

When implementing this delegate Xcode insists on an override qualifier for the func.  If it is a "delegate" function, then what code/functionality up the hierarchy am I overriding and should I care?  Inserting super.controlTextDidEndEditing in the implementation simply led to an infinite loop.  My comprehension (perhaps faulty/incomplete) of a delegate has been that it defines a signature that the implementation matches.

The context is test panel with an TextField and Label dropped into a ViewController, a trivial test exercise.  The only scenario that I can arrive at is that somewhere in the hierarchy above the ViewController some other class is already implementing controlTextDidEndEditing, which leads to the override requirement as soon as I try to implement it, which implies that I am destroying some existing level of functionality.  I did experiment with subclassing NSTextField with the same "override" required result.

Can anyone further my education by explaining the ins and outs of this ?

Thanks,

Alan.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of an obsolete design pattern in older Objective-C code that doesn't map well to Swift.  (It's more of a problem with the earliest AppKit code rather than UIKit.  Expect Apple to continue to clean up these issues as time goes on.)

[controlTextDidEndEditing](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/controlTextDidEndEditing:) isn't actually part of the `NSTextFieldDelegate` protocol (or any other protocols).  Instead, it's declared as an Objective-C ["informal protocol"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010058/informal-protocol-in-objective-c):

```
@interface NSObject(NSControlSubclassNotifications)
- (void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)obj;
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj;
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj;
@end
```

An informal protocol is like a class extension without an implementation, and their use dates back to a time when Objective-C didn't support formal protocols or optional protocol methods.

Swift doesn't have informal protocols.  Instead, it appears as an extension to `NSObject`.

```
extension NSObject {
    func controlTextDidBeginEditing(obj: NSNotification)
    func controlTextDidEndEditing(obj: NSNotification)
    func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification)
}
```

But Swift doesn't know that this is an informal protocol.  As a result, Swift will let you call `controlTextDidEndEditing()` on any `NSObject`, even though NSObject does not implement that method.

Likewise, when you implement one of these methods in your own class, Swift will force you to use the `override` keyword because it thinks you're overriding a method on `NSObject`, even though that's not the case.

Comment: Ahhh, so the apple swift doco for NSControl that describes them as delegates is describing functional intent rather than implementation reality.  Good answer, I am now comfortable that the override requirement is just, really what I think of as, syntactic noise.   Swift, I will say, is vastly quieter in that area than Objective C.  A language that I already enjoy coding in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't override delegates, you override getters and setters. BUT, classes like UITableViewController *conform* to the delegate and the datasource, which means they already implement the methods. You override them because, yes, the superclass implements those already.

When you override delegate methods, I don't think you make a superclass call unless the superclass actually performs some function. `NSTextField`'s `controlTextDidEndEditing` is probably implemented by `NSTextField` itself as an empty implementation, which is why you need to override.

Comment: That agrees with my current comprehension of what is happening, but I am still puzzled as to why, as a designer, you would design a class to adopt a protocol and then implement an optional function within that protocol with a empty implementation forcing those using the class to override a protocol function.  As a designer I would only implement the protocol methods of specific value to the class that I am creating.  Hence the "I cannot see why it is this way"

Comment: This is a common pattern for classes that declare a protocol that they want their subclass to conform to. They conform to it themselves by having a default implementation (to prevent empty implementation and crashes), so your subclass automatically inherits from the implementation and can choose to override particular methods. An example is `UITableView`'s `-numberOfSectionsInTableView` that automatically returns 1 by default. Just a pattern, nothing special.

Comment: Also, controlTextDidEndEditing isn't actually a protocol, I believe its a class method that you inherit and override, that gets called when text ends editing.